# Syntax error when running materialized view refresh concurrently in Azure Flexible Server for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views, azure-postgresql

I'm encountering a syntax error when attempting to refresh a materialized view concurrently in Azure Flexible Server for PostgreSQL v11.22.

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY data.mv_summary WITH DATA;
```

Here are the details of the error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "_2"
LINE 1: CREATE TEMP TABLE "pg_temp_8"."pg_temp_3403908"_2 AS SELECT ...
^
QUERY: CREATE TEMP TABLE "pg_temp_8"."pg_temp_3403908"_2 AS SELECT mv.ctid AS tid, 
newdata.*::"pg_temp_8"."pg_temp_3403908" AS newdata FROM "data"."mv_summary" mv FULL 
JOIN "pg_temp_8"."pg_temp_3403908" newdata ON ("newdata"."workspace_id" 
OPERATOR("pg_catalog".=) "mv"."workspace_id" AND newdata.* OPERATOR(pg_catalog.*=) 
mv.*) WHERE newdata.* IS NULL OR mv.* IS NULL ORDER BY tid
```

The same Materialized view concurrent refresh works in another Azure flexible server with the same version of Postgres.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: There really syntax error CREATE TEMP TABLE "pg_temp_8"."pg_temp_3403908"_2. Maybe, you want CREATE TEMP TABLE "pg_temp_8"."pg_temp_3403908_2"?

Comment: @ValNik: I'm not creating these tables. When I do the concurrent refresh Postgres itself creates them for doing the refresh. Not sure why there is a syntax error for queries that is generated by Postgres

Comment: This query `CREATE TEMP TABLE ...` is not yours? If not, ask Azure about what is going on.